# ¿Cómo generar una vista HTML con Owl Carousel para Google Chart con el método foreach?

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero realizar un `slide` con `carousel` para generar un grafico de `google charts`.

Tengo dos funciones la primera busca las distintas semanas que tiene una mandante x para las diferentes rutas.

```
function fetchRoute_chart($idmandante)
{
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id_semana, tramo 
            FROM ".$db_table_prefix."route, ".$db_table_prefix."mandante
    WHERE ab_route.id_mandante = ab_mandante.id and ab_route.id_mandante  = ?
    ");

   $stmt->bind_param("i", $idmandante);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($id_semana, $tramo);

   while ($stmt->fetch()){
    $row[] = array('id_semana'=>$id_semana, 'tramo' => $tramo);
   }

   $stmt->close();
   return ($row);
}
```

`SELECT DISTINCT id_semana, tramo FROM ab_route, ab_mandante WHERE ab_route.id_mandante = ab_mandante.id and ab_route.id_mandante = 1`

Luego, tengo otra función que llena los charts según el mandante, la semana y el tramo.

```
function fetchRoute_charts($idsemana,$tramo)
{
   global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 

   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ab_route.id,distancia_acu,pm10,
                               CASE 
                                  WHEN pm10 <= 299 THEN 'color: green' 
                                  WHEN pm10 >= 600 THEN 'color: red' ELSE 'color: yellow' 
                                END as color
                               FROM ".$db_table_prefix."route,".$db_table_prefix."mandante
                              WHERE ab_route.id_mandante = ab_mandante.id and   id_semana = ?
                                and tramo ='".$tramo."'
                            ORDER BY `id` ASC");
    
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $idsemana);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $distancia_acu, $pm10,$color);

    while ($stmt->fetch()){
       $row[] = array('id'=>$id, 'distancia_acu' => $distancia_acu,  'pm10' => $pm10, 'color' => $color);
    }

    $stmt->close();
    return ($row);
}
```

Ahora se debería generar el código para los distintos charts, que para el caso son 32 y los despliego así:

```
<div id='chart_div_{$i}' style='width:200; height:150'></div>"
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

 var data = google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable1?>);

  var options = {
      lineWidth: 0.5,
        series: { 0: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },},
        colors: ['#687074'],
        pointSize : 0.5,
        fontName: 'Arial',
        fontSize: 11,
        chart: {
        title: 'Tramo',
        },
        hAxis: {
                title: 'Distancia acumulada en mts', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1400, format: '#.###',
                ticks: [100, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400],
                gridlines: { count: 10 } 
            },
        vAxis: {title: 'PM10|ug/m3', minValue: 0, maxValue: 6000, format: '#.###'},
        legend: 'none',
    };
      
  var charts = [];
        var views = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1; i++) {
            views.push(new google.visualization.DataView(data));
            views[i].setColumns([0, i + 1]);
            charts.push(new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div_' + i)));
            charts[i].draw(views[i], options);
        }
        
        
}
```

pero el resultado es blanco, no muestra nada.

Código comppleto:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 column">
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">   

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("../models/config.php");
// lo asigne fijo para el ejemplo pero se obtiene por get.

$idmandante=1;


$routeData = fetchRoute_chart($idmandante);
$i = 0;
foreach ($routeData as $v1)
    {
        $idsemana=$v1['id_semana'];
        $tramo=$v1['tramo'];
                        
                    $rows = array();
                    $table = array();
                    $table['cols'] = array(
                  
                    array('label' => '', 'type' => 'number'),
                    array('label' => '', 'type' => 'number'),
                    array('type' => 'string', 'p' => array('role' => 'style'))
                    );
                    
                    $routeDatas = fetchRoute_charts($idsemana,$tramo);
                    
                    
                    foreach ($routeDatas as $r){
                         echo "<div id='chart_div_{$i}' style='width:200; height:150'></div>";
                        
                        $temp = array();
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (integer) $r['distancia_acu']); 
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (integer) $r['pm10']); 
                        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['color']); 
                        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
                  
                    }

                $table['rows'] = $rows;
                $jsonTable1 = json_encode($table);
                $i++;
                
    }
                                                            
                        
?>
</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>


    <!-- Demo -->

    <style>
    #owl-demo .item img{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 350%;
    }
    </style>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true,
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem : true

      });
    });
    </script> 

    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {

     var data = google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable1?>);

      var options = {
          lineWidth: 0.5,
            series: { 0: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },},
            colors: ['#687074'],
            pointSize : 0.5,
            fontName: 'Arial',
            fontSize: 11,
            chart: {
            title: 'Tramo',
            },
            hAxis: {
                    title: 'Distancia acumulada en mts', minValue: 0, maxValue: 1400, format: '#.###',
                    ticks: [100, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400],
                    gridlines: { count: 10 } 
                },
            vAxis: {title: 'PM10|ug/m3', minValue: 0, maxValue: 6000, format: '#.###'},
            legend: 'none',
        };
          
      var charts = [];
            var views = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1; i++) {
                views.push(new google.visualization.DataView(data));
                views[i].setColumns([0, i + 1]);
                charts.push(new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div_' + i)));
                charts[i].draw(views[i], options);
            }
            
            
    }
    </script>
```

He probado varias formas pero no logro generar la vista, si lo hago para un sola semana queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Hay algún error en PHP?¿Aparece algún error en la consola de JavaScript? El código generado podría también ser útil

Comment: Si imprimo a pantalla los  (echo $jsonTable1 = json_encode($table)."<hr>"; echo $i++."<hr>";), se generan todos.

Comment: El problema creo que esta acá: var charts = [];
            var views = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1; i++) {
                views.push(new google.visualization.DataView(data));
                views[i].setColumns([0, i + 1]);
                charts.push(new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div_' + i)));
                charts[i].draw(views[i], options);
            }. En el for data.getNumberOfColumns